# Complex analysis prove inequality

Tags: analysis

Prove that  $|e^z - 1| \le e^{|z|} - 1$
for all complex number $z$

How to prove this? I have tried a lot, like z=x+yi. But it doesn't give a way to correctly solve this problem

Comment: Please read [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488241/proving-the-inequality-ez-1-leq-ez-1). You should replace $<$ with $\le$, since the two sides of your inequality are equal when $z = 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicat: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488241/proving-the-inequality-ez-1-leq-ez-1?lq=1

Comment: Is that $|e^{z-1}|$ or $|e^z - 1|$.  The letter is just the triangle inequality.